# merge two DataFrame with two columns and keep the same order with original indexes in the result

Tags: pandas

I have two pandas data frames. Both data frames have two key columns and one value column for merge. I want to keep the same order with original indexes in the merged result.

- The keys and values might be missing or changed in the other data frame.
- The order of data are important. You can't sort them by the keys or values in the merged result.

It should looks like this:

[image]

> `df1_index` / `df2_index` / `results` are just used for demonstration.

I tried to use `merge` with `outer`:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "key1": ['K', 'K', 'A1', 'A2', 'B1', 'B9', 'C3'],
    "key2": ['a5', 'a4', 'a7', 'a9', 'b2', 'b8', 'c1'],
    "Value1": ['apple', 'guava', 'kiwi', 'grape', 'banana', 'peach', 'berry'],
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "key1": ['K', 'A1', 'A3', 'B1', 'C2', 'C3'],
    "key2": ['a9', 'a7', 'a9', 'b2', 'c7', 'c1'],
    "Value2": ['apple', 'kiwi', 'grape', 'banana', 'guava', 'orange'],
})

merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how="outer", on=['key1', 'key2'])
```

but it just added missing keys in the end of rows:

[image]

How do I merge and align them up?

Comment: can you exlain why K-a9 should come before K-a4?. One is from DF1 and the other from DF2 and I don;t see how you defined their order

Comment: @BingWang The order in key1/key2 is not guaranteed. It could be `K-a5` / `K-a4` / `K-a9`. I just care about `df1_index` & `df2_index`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when constructing the merged dataframe, get the index values from each dataframe.

```
merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how="outer", on=['key1', 'key2'])
```

use `combine_first` to combine `index_x` & `index_y`

```
merged_df['combined_index'] =merged_df.index_x.combine_first(merged_df.index_y)
```

sort using `combined_index` & `index_x` dropping columns which are not needed & resetting index.

```
output = merged_df.sort_values(
    ['combined_index', 'index_x']
).drop(
    ['index_x', 'index_y', 'combined_index'], axis=1
).reset_index(drop=True)
```

This results in the following output:

```
  key1 key2  Value1  Value2
0    K   a5   apple     NaN
1    K   a9     NaN   apple
2    K   a4   guava     NaN
3   A1   a7    kiwi    kiwi
4   A3   a9     NaN   grape
5   A2   a9   grape     NaN
6   B1   b2  banana  banana
7   C2   c7     NaN   guava
8   B9   b8   peach     NaN
9   C3   c1   berry  orange
```

Comment: Awesome! It works.

Do I need to build `index_x` & `index_y` manually in `df1` & `df2`? Is there any convenient way to access the indexes in `df1` & `df2` after merged?

Comment: you'd have to build get the indexes by doing `df1.reset_index()` & `df2.reset_index()` respectively, before merging.